# Passing variable in Jquery css background size. Not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to pass a variable in Jquery `.css({"property" : "value"})` function but it isn't working, below is the code that doesn't work.

```
 window.onload = function() {
   var windowWidth = window.innerwidth;
   var htmlBg = windowWidth*(1.5) ;
   $('html').css({
      "background-size" : htmlBg + "px"
   });
}
window.onresize = function() {
   var windowWidth = window.innerwidth;
   var htmlBg = windowWidth*(1.5) ;
   $('html').css({
      "background-size" : htmlBg + "px"
   });
}
```

Although if I provide direct numbers, it works fine, below is that code which works.

```
 window.onload = function() {
   var windowWidth = window.innerwidth;
   var htmlBg = windowWidth*(1.5) ;
   $('html').css({
      "background-size" : 100 + "px"
   });
}
window.onresize = function() {
   var windowWidth = window.innerwidth;
   var htmlBg = windowWidth*(1.5) ;
   $('html').css({
      "background-size" : 100 + "px"
   });
}
```

I searched the question and all of them showed syntactical errors but I guess this is the right syntax.

Comment: Try printing `htmlBg` in console

Comment: try var windowWidth = $(window).innerwidth(); and check in console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following:

```
var windowWidth = window.innerwidth;
```

to

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
```

**Explaination:**

In your code, because of the typo, `window.innerwidth` is undefined. So,
window.innerwidth*(1.5) gives **NaN**

Comment: Oh Thanks! New in Js , didn't knew the caps .

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/) for JQuery's `.innerWidth()`:

> This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for
>   these, use `.width()` instead.

```
window.onload = function() {
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var htmlBg = windowWidth*(1.5) ;
   $('html').css({
      "background-size" : 100 + "px"
   });
}
window.onresize = function() {
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var htmlBg = windowWidth*(1.5) ;
   $('html').css({
      "background-size" : 100 + "px"
   });
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `$(window).width()`.

Comment: Thank You. Your answer is also very helpful. Unfortunately I can only choose one.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. My answer was geared more towards JQuery than pure JS's .innerWidth. Good luck.